# 'faucet.rinkeby.io' says cannot reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again

Tags: microsoft-edge, solidity, ether

I am seeking ether from faucet.rinkeby and I cannot get pass this problem and receive my ether.

Comment: that server goes down too often. You need to wait, sometimes it takes days. when server is back, fuel your account. send me your address I send you 1 ether. then delete the question :) this type of question is not allowed

Comment: Does the issue happen in all browsers, like Edge, Chrome, Firefox and so on? You can try in several browsers to see if it works. You can also clear browser data and cache and try again. I think the issue is more related with the website.